# Fusion-Icon does not show up in system tray

Tags: compiz, unity-2d

I can't find a solution for my problem online:

I'm running Unity 2D in Ubuntu 11.10 and want to enable compiz effects. I installed compiz config settings manager, and Fusion-Icon, but when I start Fusion-Icon nothing happens. When I execute it from terminal it stucks at lines like "setting update 'command'" or "setting update 'next_key'"

I already set the whitelist for the panel to 'all'.

Anyone knows what I'm missing?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Displex](http://sourceforge.net/p/displex/home/Home/). It provides the same options as the Fusion Icon, and works with Unity/AppIndicators.

(*It will also work in most other desktop environments where you can run compiz*).

Note, if it does not run try the following:

```
I installed the deb and tried starting DisPlex from the app menu but nothing
happened. So I ran "indicator-displex" from terminal. At some point it showed
"Value error: gconf key /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop has no value"
so I had to manually add a value and typed
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop" --type bool true
ran it again and got the same error for
/apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled,
so the same procedure and that was it.
```

Taken from Schubibuntu's comment.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it worked. Although I had to solve some smaller problems that I'd like to post for later visitors:

Comment: I installed the deb and tried starting DisPlex from the app menu but nothing happened. So I ran "indicator-displex" from terminal. At some point it showed 

"Value error: gconf key /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop has no value" so I had to manually add a value and typed

gconftool-2 --set "/apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop" --type bool true

ran it again and got the same error for /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled, so the same procedure and that was it.

So again, thanks Roland ;-)

Comment: @Schubibuntu: glad to help :D! You can edit those details into my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are missing the "Notification Area" from your top panel.
To add it, Super+Alt + right-click on the top panel, and double-click "Notification Area"