# displex indicator not working in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, indicator

I have installed Displex 0.7.2 from [Source Forge](http://sourceforge.net/p/displex/home/Home/). But I am not getting any indicator when i run  `indicator-displex` instead I get the following error

```
spv@matrix:(~)$ indicator-displex 

(indicator_displex.py:5120): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(indicator_displex.py:5120): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(indicator_displex.py:5120): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(indicator_displex.py:5120): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
A saved configuration file was found.  Its contents are:
{'metacity_start_cmd': 'metacity --replace &', 'intel_gma_aiglx': False, 'ignore_desktop_hints': True, 'sm_disable': True, 'displex_menu_sccsm': True, 'displex_onstart_restart_compiz': False, 'loose_binding': False, 'compiz_start_cmd': 'compiz --replace --sm-disable --ignore-desktop-hints ccp &', 'indirect_rendering': False, 'displex_menu_compiz_opts': True, 'fast_filter': False, 'no_fbo': False, 'displex_version': '.71', 'displex_verbose': False, 'displex_menu_ccsm': True}

versions are the same.  Using saved settings.
Settings restored from configuration file:
{'metacity_start_cmd': 'metacity --replace &', 'intel_gma_aiglx': False, 'ignore_desktop_hints': True, 'sm_disable': True, 'displex_menu_sccsm': True, 'displex_onstart_restart_compiz': False, 'loose_binding': False, 'compiz_start_cmd': 'compiz --replace --sm-disable --ignore-desktop-hints ccp &', 'indirect_rendering': False, 'displex_menu_compiz_opts': True, 'fast_filter': False, 'no_fbo': False, 'displex_version': '.71', 'displex_verbose': False, 'displex_menu_ccsm': True}
------------
************************************************************
====================================
DisPlex
System Information
------------------------------------
Compiz Effects Installed     : True
     Compiz 0.9.6
Compiz CCSM Installed        : True
Compiz Simple CCSM Installed : False
Emerald Decorations Installed: False
GTK Window Decorations       : True
Disper Installed             : False
AcerHK GUI Installed         : False
====================================
************************************************************

**
compiz --replace --sm-disable --ignore-desktop-hints ccp &
**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/indicator-displex/indicator_displex.py", line 1581, in <module>
    control = IndicatorDispex()
  File "/usr/share/indicator-displex/indicator_displex.py", line 220, in __init__
    self.set_menu()
  File "/usr/share/indicator-displex/indicator_displex.py", line 1071, in set_menu
    desktop_state = self.gconf.get_value('/apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop')     # Get current value from gconf
ValueError: gconf key /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop has no value
```

Please tell me what to do to get the indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running these commands:

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop" --type bool true 
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled" --type bool true
```

And try to run `indicator-displex` again.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But what do those commands mean (specifically the second one)

Comment: I simply googled the last line in your error message.. That led me to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70674/fusion-icon-does-not-show-up-in-system-tray), and one of the comments by Schubibuntu held the answer. Apparently, indicator-displex depends on those two Gconf (Gnome Configurator) values to launch, but they don't seem to be initialized properly. Running the above commands initializes the values and allows the app to launch. What the two settings actually do can be found [here](http://people.gnome.org/~bmsmith/gconf-docs/C/), or with a quick Google search ;)

Answer (score 0):

This indicator was updated recently. (March 2015) it is available from sourceforge.net.