# Why does fusion icon not work in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, compiz

When I start the compiz fusion icon Application from the shell I get the following output but no icon and no GUI:

```
$ fusion-icon --no-start
 * Detected Session: gnome
 * Searching for installed applications...
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : default
Initializing decor options...done
 * NVIDIA on Xorg detected, exporting: __GL_YIELD=NOTHING
 * Using the GTK Interface
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fusion-Icon does not show up in system tray](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70674/fusion-icon-does-not-show-up-in-system-tray)

Answer (score 0):

I've just come accross this myself. It is my understanding that the Unity panel's behaviour is not the same as the old gnome panel. It shows only applet/indicators not a full notification tray. My work around is to use Cairo-Dock compiz/window manager switcher. That is until someone turns fusion-icon into an indicator/applet (if ever).